# What apps need to be saved on internal memory in the S4?

Tags: internal-storage, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have read [online](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/04/30/samsung-galaxy-s4-32gb/) that 16GB version comes at around 8GB instead. And that Burst Mode can only save on internal memory.

So I would like to know, what other Apps cannot save on an external memory card, and require internal memory storage to install correctly ?

Comment: Sorry that we cannot provide a list. And it might even be much, much shorter to list apps which do *not* require internal storage. All of them do, as a) they are installed to `/data/app` (even *Apps2SD* does not move the entire app), b) their data go to `/data/data/package_name` (unless you use *Data2SD* on a rooted device).

Comment: @Izzy thanks for replying, can they be moved to external storage though ??

Comment: Not all, and (at least without root) not completely. If they e.g. provide services, widgets, etc, they can't be moved to external storage. Further, the app must support that itself. While on a rooted device you might be able to "trick the system" using *Link2SD* and *Data2SD*, this might not work for all apps either; e.g. the SDCard is mounted only after `boot_completed`, so apps installed there won't be able to automatically start after reboot (as they will miss the `boot_completed` broadcast).

Comment: @Izzy Oh I see. Well what about Burst Mode ?? Can rooting the device force images to be stored on external memory ?